# How to scroll to an accordion *inside* an opened accordion?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following structure (might have gotten the copy/paste wrong after the content reduction). It's basically a collapse element inside a collapse element.

I also have the following code, used to scroll to the opened accordion element once clicked:

```
$(".accordion").on("shown.bs.collapse", function() {
    var myEl = $(this).find('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(myEl).offset().top - 6
    }, 500);
});
```

This snippet works - as long as the accordion element **does not** have a child accordion. With the child accordion, what happens is that once opening the parent accordion and then the child accordion, it scrolls to the child element but then scrolls to the parent element.

What do I need to modify in the JavaScript snippet to get this working?
I'm pretty sure the current issue happens due to the use of `.prev`.

```
<div class="panel-group accordion" id="application-migration" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="migrate-hybrid">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#hybrid-migration" href="#collapseMigrateHybrid" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMigrateHybrid"> ... </a>
                    </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseMigrateHybrid" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="migrate-hybrid">
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <div class="panel-group accordion" id="setupCordova" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="setupCordova">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="preventScroll" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#setupCordova" data-target="#collapseCordova" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCordova"> ... </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseCordova" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="setupCordova">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            ...
                            ...
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `shown.bs.collapse` event is fired for both accordions when you open the child accordion.

### UPD. You can avoid the second event by [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/t1wqbxwh/

```js
$(".accordion").on("shown.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    var myEl = $(this).find('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(myEl).offset().top - 6
    }, 500);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<div class="panel-group accordion" id="application-migration" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="migrate-hybrid">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#hybrid-migration" href="#collapseMigrateHybrid" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMigrateHybrid"> ... </a>
                    </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseMigrateHybrid" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="migrate-hybrid">
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <div class="panel-group accordion" id="setupCordova" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="setupCordova">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="preventScroll" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#setupCordova" data-target="#collapseCordova" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCordova"> ... </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseCordova" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="setupCordova">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>...</p>
                            <p>...</p>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### You can try to use `a[aria-expanded="false"]' ).click`

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/soc0rp3w/

```js
$( 'a[aria-expanded="false"]' ).click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 6
    }, 500);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<div class="panel-group accordion" id="application-migration" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="migrate-hybrid">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#hybrid-migration" href="#collapseMigrateHybrid" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMigrateHybrid"> ... </a>
                    </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseMigrateHybrid" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="migrate-hybrid">
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <div class="panel-group accordion" id="setupCordova" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="setupCordova">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="preventScroll" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#setupCordova" data-target="#collapseCordova" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCordova"> ... </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseCordova" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="setupCordova">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>...</p>
                            <p>...</p>
                            <p>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Almost. What the existing code also did is sort of auto-correct the positioning. Lets say if you open a collapsible and the parent moved off screen then it would also re-focus... hrmm.

Comment: I also noticed that the "top - 6" makes no effect.

Comment: @IdanAdar Unfortunately, the `shown.bs.collapse` event is fired for both accordions when you open the child accordion.

Comment: @IdanAdar  You can test `$(this).offset().top - 20` or `$(this).parent().parent().offset().top - 6`. The effect can be seen.

Comment: @IdanAdar Not sure I understand about focusing. Please explain me once more time what do you want to achieve. Can [jQuery's .focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) help you?

Comment: I'll see tomorrow if I am able to produce some video of the problem before and after the code change based on this answer. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @IdanAdar Ok I'll be waiting for your message.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have another solution. You can avoid the second event by [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). Check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/t1wqbxwh/ I've udated my answer.

Comment: That said, I think this created a new issue... the layout is: a group of 3 accordions: the first accordion has a child accordion, the other accordions do not. Now what happens is that if the first accordion is open and then you open the second or third (not the child) then it scrolls to back to the first (which is still open). The stopPropagation helped with the child of the first accordion, but could it also prevent scrolling for other "parent" accordions? :) typically what have happened was that an accordion would automatically close itself when opening another accordion in the same group.

Comment: Okay, fixed that. Had some mixed up IDs.